# SBT exit on Failed Karma Tests

Tags: unit-testing, sbt, karma-jasmine

I have an angular app running on the Play framework.
I have added in my Karma/Jasmine test suite and run it as part of "sbt test" with the following build.sbt config...

```
// run the angular JS unit tests (karma & jasmine)
lazy val jsTest = taskKey[Int]("jsTest")
jsTest in Test := {
    "test/js/node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js" !
}
test := Def.taskDyn {
    val exitCode = (jsTest in Test).value
    if (exitCode == 0)
    Def.task {
        (test in Test).value
    }
    else Def.task()
}.value
```

However if one of the tests fails, sbt does not seem to exit...

```
Chrome 50.0.2661 (Mac OS X 10.10.5): Executed 90 of 90 (1 FAILED) (0.512 secs / 0.453 secs)
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed 02-Jun-2016 12:11:13
```

After running sbt test I also run sbt dist and I don't want this to happen if any of the tests fail. I want sbt to exit if either the JS or scala tests fail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're letting the SBT `test` task succeed even if the exit code from Karma isn't `0`.  The simplest fix is to just throw an exception in that case, and SBT will detect it as the task failing:

```
  lazy val jsTest = taskKey[Int]("jsTest")
  jsTest in Test := {
    "test/js/node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js" !
  }
  test := Def.taskDyn {
    val exitCode = (jsTest in Test).value
    if (exitCode == 0)
      Def.task {
        (test in Test).value
      }
    else sys.error("Karma tests failed with exit code " + exitCode)
  }.value
```

But now you're in a strange situation, where the `jsTest` task is technically still succeeding even though the tests fail.  It would be more proper to make the `jsTest` task check the error code, and the `test` task depend on it:

```
  lazy val jsTest = taskKey[Unit]("jsTest")
  jsTest in Test := {
    val exitCode = "test/js/node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js" !
    if (exitCode != 0) {
      sys.error("Karma tests failed with exit code " + exitCode)
    }
  }
  test := Def.taskDyn {
    (jsTest in Test).value
    Def.task((test in Test).value)
  }.value
```

If you're OK with having the JS tests and the Scala tests run in parallel, you can simplify it further:

```
  lazy val jsTest = taskKey[Unit]("jsTest")
  jsTest in Test := {
    val exitCode = "test/js/node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js" !
    if (exitCode != 0) {
      sys.error("Karma tests failed with exit code " + exitCode)
    }
  }
  test := {
    (jsTest in Test).value
    (test in Test).value
  }
```

Comment: "test/js/node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js" !
must be in parenthesis